# Determine whether a given key binding is the default

Tags: key-bindings

I'm curious if there is a mechanism for determining whether a key binding is a stock (default) key binding within Emacs (or a particular package).  Whenever I mention a command to someone I generally need to check whether what I use is the default.  (It would be great to have a visual indication of the customization in the `describe-key`/`describe-key-briefly` output!)

Given the basic structure of keymaps I imagine that it isn't possible to judge the modification state from the keymaps themselves.  I think it would be necessary to attach advice to `define-key` prior to customizations and then simply track them.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that `bind-key` does almost exactly this!  `describe-personal-keybindings` displays a listing of all customizations made using `bind-key` (but not `define-key` directly).  I guess I'm going to remove all uses of `define-key` in my init now.

Custom bindings are tracked in `personal-keybindings` and per the docstring have the following structure:

```
((KEY . [MAP]) CMD ORIGINAL-CMD)
```

Now to customize the `describe-key`/`describe-key-briefly` output...